# Unable To Update Newtonsoft.Json From 10.0.1 to 10.0.2 Using Nuget Package Restore

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am unable to either fresh install 10.0.2 or upgrade from 10.0.1. The error I always get is tons like this one, where it clearly can't access the folders.

```
Packages directory here \Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net20\Newtonsoft.Json.xml could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.
```

If I check the packages directory I indeed only have a 10.0.1 folder, even with fresh install.

Edit: If I open a explorer window in the directory, and constantly hit F5 during "upgrade", I can see that a 10.0.2 folder gets created. It gets deleted as soon as the upgrade fails.

Edit2: could this be related to TFS somehow?

Comment: Are u executing it with Administrator rights?

Comment: Yes, running VS as admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like this issue:

[TFS Error "[file]not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it" during upgrade or uninstall when solution/project is bound to TFS source control](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2739)

> the bug is during uninstalling packages, nuget will delete package
>   files from TFS, but if user set disableSourceControllntegration to
>   true, package files are not added to TFS workplace during installing,
>   so TFS can't find those files during uninstalling. (sic)

The fix is to install the latest version of nuget.exe (3.5 or later), which you can find [here](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html).

Comment: Thank you! Awesome.